# Scrapy parse value into self.template

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

What am I doing wrong?

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.template = {'name':'','title':'','tab_1_value':{},'tab_1_description':'','tab_2_value':{},'tab_2_description':''}

def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td/div/a/@href').extract()
        page_no = response.request.url.split('=')[-1]
        with tqdm(total=len(links)) as pbar:
            for link_index, link in enumerate(links):
                pbar.set_description("Processing page {}".format(page_no))
                pbar.update(1)
                page = response.urljoin(link)
                yield scrapy.Request(page, callback=self.parse_company)

 def parse_company(self, response):
        #Successfully inscribed in self.template['name']
        self.template['name'] = response.xpath('//div/div[@class="name"]/text()').get() 
        #Successfully inscribed in self.template['title']
        self.template['title'] = response.xpath('//div/div[@class="title"]/text()').get() 
        content_links = response.xpath('//ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        
        for content_link in content_links:
            content_page = response.urljoin(content_link)
            if response.request.url.split('/')[-2] == 'tab_1':
                yield scrapy.Request(content_page, callback=self.tab_1)
            if response.request.url.split('/')[-2] == 'tab_2':
                yield scrapy.Request(content_page, callback=self.tab_2)

#It does not enter values here at all in the self.template
def tab_1(self, response):
        self.template['tab_1_value'] = self.valueSeparation(response.xpath('//div/h2/strong/span/text()').get())
        self.template['tab_1_description'] = response.xpath('//div/div/p/text()').get()

#It does not enter values here at all in the self.template
def tab_2(self, response):
        self.template['tab_2_value'] = self.valueSeparation(response.xpath('//div/h2/strong/span/text()').get())
        self.template['tab_2_description'] = response.xpath('//div/div/p/text()').get()
```

When I check if it goes into tab_1 and/or tab_2... it goes into. When I check if there are values of variables in within functions... everything is fine. It is not clear to me why these values will not be written in the self.template.

Does anyone know why the values will not be assigned to the appropriate elements in the self.template or if there is a better way to do the same?

Comment: It probably doesn't enter the callbacks because the if statement is false, put a print inside to see that. Also you can replace the split with `if 'tab_1' in response.url:`.

Comment: @SuperUser Yes, I check that. And statements are good. It goes into that function, and when I print those values, they're good as well. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better solution, but I managed to solve the problem by sending a self.template through the meta argument through yield.

Maybe this is helpful to somebody...

```
if response.request.url.split('/')[-2] == 'tab_1':
    yield scrapy.Request(content_page, callback=self.tab_1, meta={'template':self.template})
if response.request.url.split('/')[-2] == 'tab_2':
    yield scrapy.Request(content_page, callback=self.tab_2, meta={'template':self.template})
```

And the values are assigned this way:

```
def tab_1(self, response):
        response.meta.get['template']['tab_1_value'] = self.valueSeparation(response.xpath('//div/h2/strong/span/text()').get())
        response.meta.get['template']['tab_1_description'] = response.xpath('//div/div/p/text()').get()

def tab_2(self, response):
        response.meta.get['template']['tab_2_value'] = self.valueSeparation(response.xpath('//div/h2/strong/span/text()').get())
        response.meta.get['template']['tab_2_description'] = response.xpath('//div/div/p/text()').get()
```